# Error during import matplotlib, glob, pylab because of geckodriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, matplotlib, glob

When I am trying to import matplotlib or glob or pylab, it opens the geckodriver window and the geckodriver opens the firefox and opens google page on it. 
And after that , it gives an below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 19, in <module>
    import glob
  File "C:/Users/rahulku/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36\glob.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Temp\geckodriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to start browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: other os error
```

Comment: May you add your code

Comment: I am just importing those modules like 'import matplotlib' . Even while importing in the shell , it does the same thing

Comment: error doesn't seems to be import but the way you are opening the Mozilla web driver.

Comment: But the problem is that I am not even using geckodriver anywhere in the code/command, then why is it calling the geckodriver.

Comment: Actually The Selenium client bindings tries to locate the geckodriver executable from the system PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is obvious from below

```
  File "C:/Users/rahulku/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36\glob.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\rahulku\AppData\Local\Temp\geckodriver.exe')
```

As you can see you have created your own `glob.py` file which is interfering with the `import glob` statement. You should never create file names which matches system level packages name and have them in python path also.

Rename `C:/Users/rahulku/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36\glob.py` to `C:/Users/rahulku/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36\glob_custom.py` and that should fix the issue